# How to rotate a view using GLKit?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I want to rotate the view around the Z axis using the GLKit. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: have u given any trials from ur end..?

Comment: I am using GLKMatrix4MakeLookAt but Im not sure if it is possible to rotate the camera by just changing its arguments, it seems to just change the direction to which the camera is pointing to...

Comment: Yeah.. that's right, you just need to change the arguments of GLKMatrix4MakeLookAt and then you can rotate the camera.

Comment: The final three arguments to GLKMatrix4MakeLookAT() are the {x,y,z} components of a vector that defines the direction, "up". Changing the "up" direction produces the same effect as tilting the observer's head.